# Is it "make" or "makes" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

> Many clauses and phrases **make** the noun known to the listener by telling the listener which person or thing we are talking about.
>
> - Can you give me the book on the table.
> - Did you read the book which I gave you?
> - etc.

The quote is from English grammar book, this is why I suppose everything should be correct. However, '**make**' looks very weird to me. Isn't it a typo?

Comment: The verbal collocation is "to make (something) known", which is a periphrasis for **reveal**.    *The politician made his ire known via Twitter*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The subject must agree in number with its verb.

This is the rule to be applied while deciding what to opt for.  Thus, if a subject is singular, its verb must also be singular; if a subject is plural, its verb must also be plural.

**But**,

This is a case of a **compound sentence** (means made up of two or more parts.  Two or more words can be compounded or linked by joining them with any of three words:
**and**, or, and nor)

> Many clauses **and** phrases
>
> The verb is singular if the two subjects separated by **and** refer to
>   the same person or thing.

Both **Clauses** and **Phrases** are referring to the same thing. Hence,   the verb **make** is correct.

Comment: What's the source of your quoted sentences?

Answer (score 1):

I think because the subjects are clauses and phrases, which are plural, it should be 'make'.